# How to make a method inside a driver class see a subclass of another class?

Tags: java

I have this code (relevant snippet of it) in a method inside of the driver class:

```
switch (op) {
    case "+":
        arithStack.push(new AddExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
        // System.out.println(arithStack.peek() + " :top of Stack");
        break;
    case "-":
        arithStack.push(new SubExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
        break;
    case "*":
        arithStack.push(new MultExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
        break;
    case "/":
        arithStack.push(new DivExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
        break;
    case "^":
        arithStack.push(new PowExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
        break;
    }
```

The subclasses (AddExpression, SubExpressino etc...) are subclass of an abstract base class called ArithBinaryExpression. 
Here is how one of the subclasses' implementation looks like(identical to to others except the arithmetic operations):

```
    public static class AddExpression extends ArithBinaryExpression {
    public AddExpression(ArithExpression leftExp, ArithExpression rightExp) {
        super(leftExp, rightExp);
    }

    public double result() {
        ArithExpression rightExp = getRightExpression();
        ArithExpression leftExp = getLeftExpression();
        return rightExp.result() + leftExp.result();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Expression: " + "(" + leftExpression.toString() + " + " + rightExpression.toString() + ")";
    }

}
```

The compiler gives me an error at the main calls of these subclass constructors:

```
arithStack.push(new AddExpression(leftExpression, rightExpression));
```

in here compiler states:

> AddExpression cannot be resolved to be a type. How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

(HERE IS THE ArithBinaryExpression class)

```
public abstract class ArithBinaryExpression implements ArithExpression {
protected static ArithExpression leftExpression;
protected static ArithExpression rightExpression;

public boolean isSimple() {
    boolean isSimple = false;
    if (leftExpression instanceof ArithValue && rightExpression instanceof ArithValue) {
        isSimple = true;
    }
    return isSimple;
}
// constructor
public ArithBinaryExpression(ArithExpression left, ArithExpression right) {
    if (left == null) {
        leftExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else 
    leftExpression = left;

    if (right == null) {
        rightExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else
    rightExpression = right;


}
// end constructor

// accessors
public ArithExpression getLeftExpression() {
    return leftExpression;
}

public ArithExpression getRightExpression() {
    return rightExpression;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `public static class AddExpression` made *static* ? Remove the `static` and it should work if it's `public class AddExpression`. With `new` you're creating a new object, and Java doesn't allow you to create top-level static classes;

Comment: I made the change and it still won't see the subclasses' constructors.

Comment: Make sure the access to your `ArithBinaryExpression` are also updated to exclude `static` you cannot have it in the class definition and of course cannot construct an object if it's static.

Comment: @dmitryro i just added my ArithBinaryExpression class. There is not static included. Yet the main class still will not recognize the subclasses.

Comment: They need to be properly imported - verify the file has *import* statements and the fact that it compiles properly. Verify where exactly those classes are defined and make sure they are imported in the *addexpression.java* file.

Comment: You're conflating interfaces and class names - your class name has same name as the interface you're trying to implement - the names cannot be same `AddExpression` - if there's not such interface implemented, remove, if there is - rename your class accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` from class definition:

```
public class AddExpression extends ArithBinaryExpression {
    public AddExpression(ArithExpression leftExp, ArithExpression rightExp) {
        super(leftExp, rightExp);
    }

    public double result() {
        ArithExpression rightExp = getRightExpression();
        ArithExpression leftExp = getLeftExpression();
        return rightExp.result() + leftExp.result();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Expression: " + "(" + leftExpression.toString() + " + " + 
                rightExpression.toString() + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       // create it here using new AddExpression ...
    }
}
```

Java doesn't allow you to create top-level static classes; In Java you cannot use `new` to create a new object if it's `static`.

`public class AddExpression` has to be **the only** public class in file *addexpression.java* with all other classes properly imported or defined.

To see if it gets properly created, use your

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   // create it here using new AddExpression ...
}
```